# Existe un nuevo metodo para encontrar archivos logs que anteriormente se encontraban en la ruta Android/data?? con android 11 ya no los visualizo?

Tags: html, android-layout

Existe un nuevo metodo para encontrar archivos logs que anteriormente se encontraban en la ruta Android/data?? con android 11 ya no los visualizo?
Anteriormente en esta ruta encontraba los archivos que se generaban con apps privadas esto con android 9 pero ahora con version 11 no los visualizo, y necesito hacer uso de ellos.

Quedo atenta.
Saludos!

Intente visualizarlos de forma fisica pero estos no se visualizan, desde apps para visualizarlos dando todos los permisos pero estos siguen sin visualizarlos.